# The name 'arPlaneManager' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I am trying to place an object parallel to a detected plane on unity, but whatever i try, the object is the wrong orientation and i cant figure out how to control rotation. I dont want to use lean touch, as i dont want the user to be able to alter it, but i just want it to work correctly on placement.

I found a piece of code from someone who had a similar problem and according to everyone else it worked, but for some reason im getting the error, The name 'arPlaneManager' does not exist in the current context.

I checked and the namespace for arPlaneManager is UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation, so it should exist, if im thinking thats the way it works. I dont know C# unfortunately.

This is the code i have and i have attached an image of my current result.

Thanks in advance.

Also i've noted out a particular section of the code, only because the script worked the same way with that code, and i didnt want the new part i used to mess anything up, although i suppose the point is, its messed up anyway.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;
 
[RequireComponent(typeof(ARRaycastManager))]
public class PlacementController : MonoBehaviour
{

[SerializeField]
private GameObject placedPrefab;




public GameObject PlacedPrefab
{
    get 
    {
        return placedPrefab;
    }
    set 
    {
        placedPrefab = value;
    }
}

private ARRaycastManager arRaycastManager;

void Awake() 
{
    arRaycastManager = GetComponent<ARRaycastManager>();
}

bool TryGetTouchPosition(out Vector2 touchPosition)
{
    if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        touchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
        return true;
    }

    touchPosition = default;

    return false;
}

void Update()

{
    if(!TryGetTouchPosition(out Vector2 touchPosition))
        return;

    //if(arRaycastManager.Raycast(touchPosition, hits, 
UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon))
    //{
        //var hitPose = hits[0].pose;
       // Instantiate(placedPrefab, hitPose.position, hitPose.rotation);
        
   // }


  if (arRaycastManager.Raycast(touchPosition, hits, 
TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon))
    {
        Pose hitPose = hits[0].pose;
        Quaternion orientation = Quaternion.identity;
        Quaternion zUp = Quaternion.identity;

        GetWallPlacement(hits[0], out orientation, out zUp);

        GameObject wallObj = Instantiate(placedPrefab, hitPose.position, 
orientation);
        wallObj.transform.rotation = zUp;
    }


}
private void GetWallPlacement(ARRaycastHit _planeHit, out Quaternion orientation, out 
Quaternion zUp)
{
    TrackableId planeHit_ID = _planeHit.trackableId;
    ARPlane planeHit = arPlaneManager.GetPlane(planeHit_ID);
    Vector3 planeNormal = planeHit.normal;
    orientation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, planeNormal);
    Vector3 forward = _planeHit.pose.position - (_planeHit.pose.position + 
Vector3.down);
    zUp = Quaternion.LookRotation(forward, planeNormal);
}

static List<ARRaycastHit> hits = new List<ARRaycastHit>();
}
```

[image: supposed to be a picture frame]

Comment: Sure it is not maybe `ARPlaneManager`? And well nothing in your code is called like that ... Are you missing another field like `public ARalaneManager arPlaneManager;` ...?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the quick response. That got rid of the error messages, so thank you!
Hasnt solved the issue though, any ideas about my original goal? @derHugo

Comment: Are you sure the issue is not simply in your 3D model? If you just drag it into Unity and reset its rotations how does it look like? If it hasn't the orientation you would expect then you might want to nest it under another object, use this new parent as the prefab instead and give your 3D model the desired local rotation offset relative to the new parent

Comment: Turns out i was being even more of an idiot. The UnityAREssentials comes with about 20 different projects and i was editing one for another project and thats why everything i was doing wasnt affecting it. Thanks for your help.